# Checking value agains max and min variables

Tags: python

Im trying to check a value against a min_value and a max_value but max_value could not be set, and therefor there is no max limit.

Here is some testdata I get from the atom feed Im using

```
<entry>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <f:fpdata>
             <f:max_value_a>500 000</f:max_value_a> #OPTIONAL
             <f:max_value_b>100 0000</f:max_value_b> #OPTIONAL
             <f:max_value_c>2 000 000</f:max_value_c> #OPTIONAL
             <f:max_value_d>3 000 001</f:max_value_d> #OPTIONAL
             <f:min_value_a>0</f:min_value_a>
             <f:min_value_b>500 000</f:min_value_b> #OPTIONAL
             <f:min_value_c>100 0000</f:min_value_c> #OPTIONAL
             <f:min_value_d>2 000 000</f:min_value_d> #OPTIONAL
             <f:target_1_a>1,1</f:f:target_1_a>
             <f:target_1_b>2,2</f:target_1_b> #EXIST ONLY IF <f:min_value_b> is set
             <f:target_1_c>3,3</f:target_1_c> #EXIST ONLY IF <f:min_value_c> is set
             <f:target_1_d>4,4</f:target_1_d> #EXIST ONLY IF <f:min_value_d> is set
             <f:target_2_a>10</f:f:target_2_a>
             <f:target_2_b>20</f:target_2_b> #EXIST ONLY IF <f:min_value_b> is set
             <f:target_2_c>30</f:target_2_c> #EXIST ONLY IF <f:min_value_c> is set
             <f:target_2_d>40</f:target_1_d> #EXIST ONLY IF <f:min_value_d> is set
         </f:fpdata>
     </content>
</entry>
```

## Edit:

Here is a paste of larger dataset: http://pastebin.com/r5HkWHA5

Here Is what I have tried so far

```
request = urllib2.Request(settings.FEED_URL)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (settings.FEED_USERNAME, settings.FEED_PASS)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)    

d = feedparser.parse(result)

for data in d.entries:

    test_amount = 3000000.00

    values = {}

    if (data.f_min_value_d <= test_amount) and (data.f_max_value_d >= test_amount):
        values.update({'target' : data.f_target_d})
    if (data.f_min_value_c <= test_amount) and (data.f_max_value_c >= test_amount):
        values.update({'target' : data.f_target_c})
    if (data.f_min_value_b <= test_amount) and (data.f_max_value_b >= test_amount):
        values.update({'target' : data.f_target_b})
    if (data.f_min_value_a <= test_amount) and (data.f_max_value_a >= test_amount):
        values.update({'target' : data.f_target_a})
```

If the `test_amount` is `3000000.00` I should get the `data.f_target_d` variable.

If the `test_amount` is `50000.00` I should get the `data.f_target_a` variable.

I need help to check if there is set any max_value_* (if it not set, it would mean there is no upper max limit)

## Edit 2:

Here is the code I'm using now:

```
values = {}
values.update({'query' : None})


def clean(entry, label, default='nan'):
    return float(''.join(entry.get(label, default).split()))

labels = [['f_{}_{}'.format(label, c) for label in 'min_value', 'max_value', 'target_1', 'target_2'] 
          for c in 'abcd']
for data in d.entries:
    for min_label, max_label, target_1_label, target_2_label in labels:
        min_value = clean(data, min_label, '-inf')
        max_value = clean(data, max_label, 'inf')
        if min_value < test_amount <= max_value:
            target = clean(data, target_label)

            values.update({'target_1' : clean(data, target_1_label),  'target_2' : clean(data, target_2_label), 'query' : True})
```

I don't get any errors, but `target_1_label` and `target_2_label` returns `nan` on all the data.

## Edit 3

Ended up doing it like this for every letter (a,b,c,d)

```
if hasattr(data, 'f_max_value_d'):
    max_value_d = int(data.f_max_value_d.replace(u'\xa0',''))
else:
    max_value_d = None

if hasattr(data, 'f_min_value_d'):
    min_value_d = int(data.f_min_value_d.replace(u'\xa0',''))
else:
    min_value_d = None


if (min_value_d is None or min_value_d <= test_amount) and (max_value_d is None or max_value_d >= test_amount) and min_value_d is not None:
    values.update({'target1' : int(data.f_target_1_d.replace(u'\xa0','')), 'target2' : int(data.f_target_2_d.replace(u'\xa0','')), 'query' : True})
```

Not very pythonic, but it works.

Comment: Can you paste the code that grabs the min/max values from the input file?

Comment: there is no f_max_value_d in the input. Your question is still very unclear.

Comment: @mario23: Sorry if it is unclear. if there is no f_max_value_d or f_max_value_c or f_max_value_b or f_max_value_a, it would mean that there is not an upper limit, and that is the problem Im trying to solve/check for.

Comment: Do your min and max values cover all possibilities above 0, and what do you want to happen if your test_amount is equal to one of the boundaries, e.g. `test_amount = 500000`?

Comment: If the `test_amount = 500000` I would like to get back `f_target_a`
If the `test_amount = 500001` I would like to get back `f_target_b`

Comment: min and max should cover all possibilities above 0 (the value is never less than 0), but there is possibilites that there is only set a `min_value_a = 0`, and in those cases `data.f_min_value_d <= test_amount` should just return `False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to check whether the `f_max_value_...` is in the data before comparing it to your `test_amount`. However it will be easier to do this in a loop rather than typing the same comparison out 4 times. I think you will also need to convert the data to `float` for the comparisons to work.

```
labels = [['f_{}_{}'.format(label, c) for label in 'min_value', 'max_value', 'target'] 
          for c in 'abcd']
for data in d.entries:
    test_amount = 3000000
    for min_label, max_label, target_label in labels:
        if float(data[min_label]) < test_amount and (max_label not in data or test_amount <= float(data[max_label])):
            target = data[target_label]
    print target
```

Or perhaps neater, you can use `data.get` to set a default value of infinity in case the maximum is not found. Then your condition becomes:

```
if float(data[min_label]) < test_amount <= float(data.get(max_label, float('inf'))):
```

EDIT. If the minimum values may also be missing you can alter as follows to set default values for the minimum and maximum. Be careful, though: how will you know which target is the right one if only minimum values are assigned in some cases, and only maximum values assigned in other cases? You will need to check this is rightly assigning the targets given your particular input data.

2nd EDIT. I added a function to remove all whitespace from the string and convert to float in case there are spaces (including non-breaking spaces) inside it.

3rd EDIT. I made the default 'nan' in case no number is found corresponding to a particular labels. This will handle missing values in the data without raising an error.

```
def clean(entry, label, default='nan'):
    return float(''.join(entry.get(label, default).split()))

labels = [['f_{}_{}'.format(label, c) for label in 
           'min_value', 'max_value', 'target_1', 'target_2'] for c in 'abcd']
for data in d.entries:
    for min_label, max_label, target_label_1, target_label_2 in labels:
        min_value = clean(data, min_label, '-inf')
        max_value = clean(data, max_label, 'inf')
        if min_value < test_amount <= max_value:
            target = data[target_label_1], data[target_label_2]
    print target
```

Comment: You are treating `data` as a dictionary like object, are you certain that is the case here? Admittedly it would be more pythonic if it where, but IMHO we don't know that.

Comment: @Peter I'm assuming it's the [`feedparser`](http://pythonhosted.org//feedparser) module, and have tested this and it works. It's not made entirely clear in the documentation but entries seem to be dictionary-like objects and the data inside can be accessed either as object properties (`data.f_max_value_a`) or dictionary values (`data['f_max_value_a']`). E.g. see [this page](http://pythonhosted.org//feedparser/basic-existence.html) on testing for existence.

Comment: This looks great! But I get this error when I try it: `KeyError('f_min_value_d',)` The only `min_value` that is always set is `min_value_a`, but the other `min_value(b,c,d)` could also not be present like the `max_value(a,b,c,d)` could sometime not be set.

Comment: replace `float(data[min_label]) < test_amount` with `(min_label not in data or test_amount > float(data[min_label]))`

Comment: I'm not certain the float() commands are actually needed, but I haven't tested it. If the data is stored as strings it is required.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you, I think the code is almost correct, except I don't know how to convert the string values into float, or int. You can see in my question how the data is formated `2 000 000` (those who created this feed clearly does not care about others) (args like this:`u'2\xa0000\xa0000'`) I tried like this: `min_value = feed_bank.get(int(re.search('\d+', min_label).group(0)), '-inf')` but that does not work.

Comment: @Garreth00: I have to admit that I'm not overly familiar with Unicode and/or other string encodings, but if you do `float("2 000 000".replace(' ', ''))` you should get a valid number.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you for taking the time to do this! Now I get this error:
`AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'",)`

Comment: @Gareth00 that would happen if your input is missing a target value. Try altering as above; however it will return `nan` (not a number) as the target value.

Comment: @Stuart: Yes, if I change to `default='nan'` I don't get any errors, but as you pointed out, the target returns `nan` now. I would like to get the value of the target.

Comment: @Gareth00 that is because the target value is missing, I think. I have tested with your testdata above and this problem doesn't arise. If you're sure the target value is not missing then maybe post a new question with an example of input that causes the problem.

Comment: @Stuart: That should not be possible. Granted one or two from the dataset could be missing value. But all of them? I have edited my question and pasted a larger dataset, could you try again with this data? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Gareth00 The larger data set you posted has the targets in a different format from what you originally posted - `f:target_1_a` and `f:target_2_a`, etc. The code can easily be adapted to reflect this. I suggest you try adapting it and post a new question if you run into problems.

Comment: @Stuart: Updated question with my code. Would it be better to just test for min/max value, and then assign the character of the match so I could get the value of the target?